# Proving a conclusion (Logic)

Tags: logic

I had a question on how to prove a conclusion with a series of premises using deduction. From a statement such as the one below:

If you eat carefully then you will have a healthy digestive system. If you
exercise regularly you will be very fit. If you have a healthy digestive system
or you are very fit, you will live to a ripe old age.

Would you consider the following to be a conclusion one could arise from the premises or would it simply be a statement that indicated what happened?

You do not live to a ripe old age.

Would something along the lines of:

Therefore, you did not eat carefully and you did not exercise regularly.

Be more of a conclusion? or could both of them be considered conclusions.

Comment: To answer your question, both of them can be considered as separate conclusions. Your conclusion "Therefore, you did not eat carefully and you did not exercise regularly" is correct, and because this conjunction is true, it follows by the rule of inference called simplification (see the table below) that you can consider the two statements "You did not eat carefully" and "you did not exercise regularly."

Answer (score 1):

The premises are the statements that are given to you

**Premises**

1. If you eat carefully, then you will have a healthy digestive system.
2. If you exercise regularly, you will be very fit.
3. If you have a healthy digestive system or you are very fit, you will live to a ripe old age.

The conclusion that one can deduce from these premises could be simple propositions like the one that you have provided, or they could be a compound proposition, which are intricate propositions constructed using the words "and", "or", "implies", etc. These words are called logical connectives, and they each have mathematical symbols $\wedge$, $\lor$, and $\implies$, respectively.

Unfortunately, I did not get the conclusion "You do not live to a ripe old age," but I have a feeling that that was an example.

Here is what I got. I am going to introduce some propositional variables to represent various statements, then I am going to represent the premises outlined above accordingly, so that I can apply various logical manipulations (or inferences) to make the necessary deductions. I will refer to these inferences by name when appropriate, and I will attach a chart of some  basic logical connectives. I will also make use of the following logical equivalence: If I have two propositional variables $p$ and $q$, then the implication $p \implies q$ (translated to English as "If p, then q") has an equivalent form:

$$p \implies q \equiv \neg p \lor q \tag{1}$$

where $\lor$ means "or", as stated above.

Now I will introduce some propositional variables to represent some of the statements in your problem.

Let $p$ be "You eat carefully," the variable $q$ be "you have a healthy digestive system," the letter $r$ be "You exercise regularly," and symbol $s$ to denote "You are very fit," and the propositional variable $t$ to represent "you will live to a ripe old age."

Thus, here are the above premises in logical form

**Premises Logical Form**

1. $p \implies q$
2. $r \implies s$
3. $(g \lor s) \implies t$

Now, I am going to prove that the compound proposition $(g \lor s) \implies t$ is equivalent to the compound statement $(g \implies t) \wedge (s \implies t)$, and I will do so using equivalence $(1)$.

$$\begin{align}(g\lor s) \implies t \, &\equiv (\neg g \lor \neg s)\lor t \\
                                      &\equiv (\neg g \lor t) \land (\neg s \lor t) \\ 
                                      &\equiv (g \implies t) \land (s \implies t)\\
\end{align}$$

This is an important deduction, because we can now rewrite premise 3 into two new premises using the $\color{blue}{\text{logical inference of simplification}}$. Therefore, our list of premises becomes

**Updated Premises**

$1.$ $p \implies q$

$2.$ $r \implies s$

$3^*$. $g \implies t$

$4^*$. $s \implies t$

where the original premises $3$ has been replaced with the new premises $3^*$ and $4^*$.

**Conclusion**

So now for our deriving a conclusion.

Using $\color{blue}{\text{the logical inference of hypothetical syllogism}}$ on premises $1.$ and $4.$ we have the conclusion $p \implies t$.

Again appying hypothetical syllogism on premises $2.$ and $5.$, we deduce $s \implies t$.

So, two conclusions that can be derived here are "If you eat carefullly, then you will live to a ripe old age," and the other one is, "If you exercise, you will live to a ripe old age."

But if we notice that both of our conclusions have the same conclusion $t$, we can use the $\color{blue}{\text{logical inference of conjunction}}$ to combine the compound propositions $p \implies t$ and $r \implies t$ to get

$$(p \implies t) \wedge (r \implies t) \equiv (p \lor r) \implies t$$

Therefore, our equivalent conclusion is, "If you eat carefully or exercise, then you will live to a ripe old age," which sounds like a decent answer for this problem, considering the premises. Ultimately, this exercise illustrates that we can remove certain irrelevant information, like the healthy digestive system, and acknowledge the central data to arrive a clean-cut solution.

In other words, and what I'm about to say applies to every problem like the one you posted, if you absorb the premises as they are given to you, you will reason that the point of all this information is "such and such." But there must be a simpler way to get to the point (the "such and such"), so that it is short, sweet and to the point.

Here is the table of logial inferences referenced in the above answer

[image]